# Passing parameters to a callback with tkinter.after

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, parameters, callback

I'm trying to build a small control GUI for my R-pi + Arduino system. Eventually, this will have some control clickers and a scrolling window that will update every second or so with text from the serial port.

I figure the .after method is just right for what I need, but this code (stripped down) gives 2 behaviours I don't expect. First, it waits for 5000mS before first showing the GUI (with "First update" already in the scrollbox) and when I uncomment the call in update_scrollbox it hangs altogether.

I'd expect to see a blank text box, then after 5 secs it should say  "first update", then every second after it should add "next update".

Completely stuck here. Any ideas..?

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Control panel")
window.geometry('660x415')

def update_scrollbox(text):
    scr.insert(INSERT, text)
    #window.after(1000, update_scrollbox("Next update "))


scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=70, height=10)                         
scr.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)   

window.after(5000, update_scrollbox("First update "))
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `update_scrollbox` instead of passing the callback as an object.
`after` takes parameters to the callback, you can do like this:

```
window.after(5000, update_scrollbox, "First update")
```

Comment: Ah, TIL. This looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

[`after`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) expects a callback. Right now you are calling the function and passing its return value as soon as you start your program.

To pass a parameter to callback, you can use `lambda`.

```
window.after(5000, lambda: update_scrollbox("First update"))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank-you... onwards and upwards. Expect more DQ's as I attempt threading and a queue next...